# URL for JDBC SQLite Installation in eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse, sqlite, url, jdbc

I am following the steps of installation from [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite)

[image]

In the 15th step, I am not able to find the URL for database connection.

**EDIT:**

In the **2nd step**: **sqlite_jni.dll** was added to **JAVA/jre7** directory in Program Files and Program Files(x86).

In the **6th step**: **sqlite.jar** was added.

In the **8th step**: Connection URL **jdbc:sqlite:/C:/Users/Temp/db/permission.db** was given. (I manually checked the folder, but no .db file was created yet)

In the **15th step**: URL **jdbc:sqlite:/C:/Users/Temp/db/permission.db** (same as that in 8th step) was given. (I manually checked the folder, but no .db file was created yet)

In the **16th step**: On Clicking "Test Connection", it gives error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class SQLite.JDBC2x.DatabaseX
at SQLite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:113)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:298)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:81)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:53)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @LutzHorn Sqlite database

Comment: See http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-sqlite-via-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

My SQLite database file is

```
C:\__tmp\test\sqlite\jdbcTest.db
```

and the following URL works for me:

```java
String connectionURL =
        "jdbc:sqlite:/C:/__tmp/test/sqlite/jdbcTest.db";
```

Some variations on the theme are listed in the page [here](http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/).

Comment: I have not yet created sqlite db file. And if I need to create, then how to do so? The SQLite driver contains only a .jar and a .dll file.

Comment: @Codingman If the database file in the connection URL does not exist then SQLite will create it for you. (At least it did for me when I tried it just now.)